# If blank then return to default value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter

If the customer's twitter handle is blank I want it to default to another twitter handle. For this example let's say the default handle is @google.

```
twitter_handle = customer.twitter_name 
#add @ sign if user name doesn't have it
twitter_handle = '@' + customer.twitter_name.gsub.to_s('@', '') unless twitter_handle.blank?

tape_name = name.truncate(27)

"I just bought #{twitter_handle} product}"
```

I tried:

```
twitter_handle = customer.twitter_name || "@google"
twitter_handle = '@' + customer.twitter_name.to_s.gsub('@', '')
```

I know the error has to do with this line because if I comment it out it works:

```
twitter_handle = '@' + customer.twitter_name.to_s.gsub('@', '')
```

It chops off the entire user handle and just returns blank.

```
tape_name = name.truncate(27)

"I just bought #{twitter_handle} product}"
```

but I get this error:

```
Sorry, that page does not exist:
 Twitter::Error::NotFound in ProductsController#download
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a go:

## The Code

```
twitter_handle = customer.twitter_name ||= '@google'
twitter_handle[/^@/] ? nil : twitter_handle = "@#{twitter_handle}"
```

## The test without '@'

```
1.9.3p194 :001 > twitter_name = 'bjernigan52' #Set without '@' sign
 => "bjernigan52" 
1.9.3p194 :002 > twitter_handle = twitter_name ||= '@google'
 => "bjernigan52" 
1.9.3p194 :003 > twitter_handle[/^@/] ? nil : twitter_handle = "@#{twitter_handle}"
 => "@bjernigan52" 
1.9.3p194 :004 > puts twitter_handle
@bjernigan52
 => nil
```

## The Test with '@'

```
1.9.3p194 :001 > twitter_name = '@bjernigan52'  #Set with '@' sign                                   
 => "@bjernigan52" 
1.9.3p194 :002 > twitter_handle = twitter_name ||= '@google'                       
 => "@bjernigan52" 
1.9.3p194 :003 > twitter_handle[/^@/] ? nil : twitter_handle = "@#{twitter_handle}"
 => nil 
1.9.3p194 :004 > puts twitter_handle                                               
@bjernigan52
 => nil
```

Comment: thanks, works like a charm! only thing is   twitter_handle[/^@/]  removes the @ sign from the twitter handle and doesn't add an @ if their is no @ symbol present.

Comment: The `[/^@/]` is there to test if there is an @ at the beginning of the string. It shouldn't strip it actually. Check my updated answer from the test results in irb. I am using Ruby 1.9.3 by the way.

Comment: Yep it works great like that but if a user enters @bjernigan52 then the result is 2 @'s so it would look like @@bjernigan52. With gsub I was able to remove the @ sign if the user had one already in his name and then add the at sign again.

Comment: From the 2nd line of code: If it contains an @ sign, then it just returns nil, otherwise it sets twitter_handle to `'@' + twitter_handle`. I've updated the answer to show the test with an @ sign.